# How to apply an htaccess rule only on https

Tags: apache, .htaccess

So I have a protected folder on a site with an htaccess that forces https and uses basic authentication. The problem is that if I go there using http, it asks for authentication before transferring to https, and then asks for authentication again. Is there a way to make it transfer to https before it prompts me?

Here is the htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} folder
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://site.net/folder/$1 [R,L]
AuthName "Dialog prompt"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/user/site.net/folder/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

Update: I've decided to implement my own auth system to bypass this issue.

Comment: Is there any chance you could create 2 virtualhost instead of using a htaccess? Have you tried to create 2 rules?

Comment: It's a shared host so htaccess is all I have access to. I suppose I could replace basic auth and make my own auth system but.. was hoping to solve this in a simple way.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you can do to show authentication only once:

1. Set a cookie while redirecting from `http` to `https`
2. Using `SetEnvIfNoCase` disable authentication when cookie is set

Code you can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^filder https://%{HTTP_HOST}/folder%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L,NC,CO=NO_AUTH:1:%{HTTP_HOST}]

SetEnvIfNoCase COOKIE NO_AUTH=1 OKAY

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Dialog prompt"
AuthUserFile /home/user/site.net/folder/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
Order allow,deny
allow from all
deny from env=OKAY
Satisfy any
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Apache 2.4, you can apparently use the conditional structure within your htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

<If "%{HTTPS} == 'on'">
    AuthType basic
    AuthName "Private"
    AuthUserFile /path/to/passwordfile
    Require valid-user
</If>
```

Comment: Tried that, got a 500 server error. I suspect it's because of the way this host has things setup. Thanks for trying, I've decided to just go ahead and do my own auth instead.